# Updated MacBook and now "code ." command in terminal is giving error. Any ideas how to fix?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-monterey

I updated my 2020 MacBook to Monterey 12.3.1 and when I tried to open Visual Studio Code through the terminal using `code .` I got the error below

```
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

This is the same error I've gotten on different projects I've tried to open and some of those aren't even written with Python. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling 'code command from PATH' through VS but it's still returning the same error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get with `python --version && which python`?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, following, this can happen when you uninstall python2. Editing the referenced "line 6:" to invoke `python3` (instead of `python` v2) is a remedy.

- [Cannot Start VSCode from Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141819)
- [macOS 12.3 code shell command doesn't work due to Python 2 being removed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141738)